# Сериализация нескольких классов

Tags: c#, xmlparser, сериализация

На данный момент пишу XmlParser для чтения и записи xml файлов и возник вопрос. У меня очень много наследуемых классов и возник такой вопрос что делать если мне нужно сериализовать несколько классов одновременно? Для записи у меня такой метод:

```
public void Save<T>(T obj, string fileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        ser.Serialize(fs, obj);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Как видно из метода я могу сериализовать любой один класс, а что делать если допустим мне надо сериализовать вместе следующие классы: BentTube, Macro, Hole и ещё такие классы OvalTube, ConeIntersection, Slot. Заранее неизвестно какие классы должны быть сериализованы. Ведь вместе OvalTube мне допустим нужно будет сериализваоть и  Hole, Slot. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать. Можно сделать и со списком но там нужно конкретно указывать какие классы необходимо сериализовать.

Comment: в имя передавай тип обьекта, сделай фабрику которая будет понимать это имя и по нему десермальзовать их обратно...

Answer (score 2):

- Можете реализовать это примерно следующим образом:

  ```
  public static MemoryStream SerializeToMemoryStream<T>(
      IEnumerable<T> objectSequence, IFormatter formatter)
  {
      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      foreach (T what in objectSequence)
      {
          formatter.Serialize(stream, what);
      }

      return stream;
  }
  ```
- Не забудьте учесть возможные исключения при сериализации и решите для себя, будете ли вы пытаться восстановиться в исключительной ситуации.
- Дальше можете прокинуть созданный таким образом `MemoryStream` в любой другой `Stream`  с помощью метода [`CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.copyto)
- Для произвольного множества объектов этот метод может работать с `IEnumerable<object>`.
- Десериализация осуществляется аналогичным образом путем операций над `object,` которые можно отфильтровывать по типам с помощью оператора `is` или использовать что-нибудь в духе `DeserializeFromMemoryStream<T>(...)`.

Comment: Извеняюсь за глупый вопрос, а IEnumerable<Object> применить к базовому классу? Или к наследникам тоже? Структура такова: Tube это базовый класс а BentTube, OvalTube наследники, то же самое с остальными классами базовый класс Intersection наследники Cone, Slot, Macro, Hole, Slot.